# Save UIViewController and display again if needed

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create a system where a user can open a UIViewController, close out of that ViewController, and return to the same ViewController if they closed it by accident. The UIViewController is populated with data from the internet (that changes frequently) and is a long scrolling UITableView. Currently when the user enters the same UIViewController again, the data is lost and must be re-downloaded, and their previous position is lost.

On the Android version of my app, I have a ViewPager as the main view, with the main pane being the left Fragment and the opened pane as the right Fragment. When the user opens the same "submission", the Fragment is not re-created and the user returns to the same screen, and if the user clicks a new submission, the old Fragment is deleted and a new one is loaded in its place. This allows for the state to be the same and the user can go back if they closed out of the pane by accident.

I think keeping a static version of the UIViewController would be bad practice and lead to memory issues down the road, but I cannot think of another way to implement this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on Apple's docs on restoring view controller state: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html

Additionally, you will need to archive and unarchive the data being displayed in your view controller. Therefore you might want to implement the NSCoding protocol in your model classes. Once you've implemented NSCoder, you can use NSKeyedArchiver / NSKeyedUnarchiver to save and restore state for your view controller. Read up on NSCoding here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoding

Finally the App Delegate sends out notifications when your app is about to terminate or move to the background. So in this class you will need to start the whole process of saving and restoring application state. Read up on UIApplicationDelegate here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate